# Is it possible to unset root password?

Tags: backup, root

Is it possible to unset the root password once it has been set in ubuntu?

Am trying to run a backup using Arcserve R16 backups agents.  I run it as the admin user but of course it does not have root permissions without sudo, which the backup agent does not run (or support).  My thinking, to get an initial full backup, was to enable the root account and then run the backup as that user and then remove the password afterwards.  Do not think this is strictly best practice but have been scrathcing my head over this for awhile now :(

Comment: you'd need to explain how ArcServe works now. Since all the backup solutions I encountered run as `root` simply because they need to be able to access all files on the system.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Yes, it is.

```
sudo passwd -dl root
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Re-disabling_your_root_account

Comment: Of note, locking a password does not disable the account, just prevents you from accessing it via password (e.g. via authorized_key still works)

Comment: This basically resets it to the state it was in on installing Ubuntu? (`sudo` still works but direct login doesn't?)