# is this a password bug in Disco Dingo (Ubuntu 19.04)?

Tags: command-line, bash, password

Password is set successfully. - Now a friend want to use Ubuntu too on concerning notebook, but wants an easier password, than already setted password.

I tried:

> sudo passwd

... and typed the new smaller password into it and it was changed according to 19.04's message "successfully changed".

I log out and want to log in back. But the previous password is still guilty and the newer password was not saved ?!

Even after reboot new password was not set.

What is this ?

Comment: No, this is not a bug, this is By Design because `sudo passwd` affects the `root` account and not yours.

Answer (score 5):

With `sudo passwd` you change the password of the user `root`.

If the user wants to change his own password, he might use just

```
passwd
```

If you want to change his password, use

```
sudo passwd USERNAME
```

[See also](https://askubuntu.com/questions/423942/change-password-on-root-user-and-user-account)

You might want to [unset root password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104137/is-it-possible-to-unset-root-password) again.